# Put resources in a modular project maven

Tags: java, maven-3

I split my java web application in a few modules. I have five modules: model, services, util, rest and web-app. Now  each of these modules use resources, for example in the web-app module there are a few images, in the service module there are a jasper files ....

I want to ask you what is the best place to put these resources? I saw a few plugin like maven-shared-resources

[maven-shared-resources](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-shared-resources/usage.html)

Is this a used strategy to manage different kind of resources in a maven modular project?

I ask you this why I'm not able not get a few resources from a model

I use a few resource contained in the util module for the login . My trouble is that when i call the class contained also it in the util module from the web-app module i get a FileNotFoundException why it try to get a resource from the util-module.jar.

I use the following line code to try to get a resource

```
InputStream inStr = getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/myFile.jks");
```

Comment: Does keeping the resources in the modules where the resources are neeed create a problem for you?

Comment: At the [top](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-shared-resources/) of the maven-shared-resources page it says "This is a collection of templates that are specific to the Maven project. They are probably not of interest to projects other than Apache Maven." My guess is that it is not intended for managing different kinds of resources in a maven modular project.

Comment: If the appropriate resources belong to a particular project like the images to the web-app i would put them into the web-app module.